# Get the buffer layer in meters in QGIS

Tags: qgis, buffer

I'm trying to create a buffer but the layer I get is very large

[image]

Buffer settings:

[image]

Bad result:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? The idea is to have an area of influence of 10 meters

Answer (score 3):

You should use the correct CRS Projection, in your case, an UTM projection. Try to save your shapefile with an UTM projection and then use the buffer tool again.